# Basis of Complex Eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Find the eigenvalues and a basis for each eigenspace in $C^2$

$\begin{bmatrix}1&5\\-2&3\end{bmatrix}$

$\lambda = 2 \pm 3i$

For the first eigenvalue, $2 + 3i$, I got this eigenvector: 
$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-3i}{2}\\1\end{bmatrix}$
But the book says $\begin{bmatrix}{1-3i}\\2\end{bmatrix}$. This is just: $2\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1-3i}{2}\\1\end{bmatrix}$

So, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&5\\-2&3\end{bmatrix}$$

We find the eigenvalues from $|A - \lambda I| = 0$ as

$$\lambda_{1,2} = 2 ~ \pm 3i$$

We find the eigenvector of $\lambda_1 = 2 + 3i$, using the RREF of $[A - \lambda I]v_1 = 0$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & \dfrac{-1 + 3 i}{2} \\  0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\  0 \ \end{bmatrix}$$

Eigenvectors are **not unique**, and we can write (verify that each $v_1$ works)

$$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}  \dfrac{1 - 3 i}{2} \\  1 \ \end{bmatrix}~~\text{or}~~ v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}  1 - 3 i \\  2 \ \end{bmatrix}$$

For $\lambda_2's$ eigenvector, we just take the complex conjugate of $\lambda_1's$.

In other words, your result and the book's result are equivalent and both are correct.

Comment: Thank you for the write up. The book does mention that it wants a basis for eigenspace, so would my result be the correct basis, since the books result is a multiple of mine (but still spans)?

Comment: Either one is sufficient. Unless you are using one of the web answer things and it wants things to match exactly! :-)